# ImportError after upgrading python2.5 to 2.7

Tags: python, python-import

I just upgraded to python2.7.5 from 2.5 and now I get this error.

`ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.` on the following line of code:

```
set = __import__(ground[0], globals(), locals(), ['*'], level=0)
```

We cant call via `__import__` anymore?
whats a fix to this in 2.7?

Comment: And what does `ground` contain?

Comment: were you really trying to override a builtin? `set` is not a very good variable name...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [changed in Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html):

> Due to an implementation accident, if you passed a file path to the built-in `__import__()` function, it would actually import the specified file. This was never intended to work, however, and the implementation now explicitly checks for this case and raises an `ImportError`.

Your `ground` list contains filenames instead of module names.